# ! Unable to locate a Windows 10 SDK. If building fails, install the Windows 10 SDK in Visual Studio

Tags: flutter, visual-studio, flutter-doctor

I'm experiencing below error in my Wondows 10 PC during flutter installation.
I'm attaching pictures as well. I retried removal and reinstallation below versions as well as version 11 SDK.

1. Windows 10 SDK (10.0.20348.0)
2. Windows 10 SDK (10.0.19041.0)
3. Windows 10 SDK (10.0.18362.0)
   [image]

**ERROR**
"! Unable to locate a Windows 10 SDK. If building fails, install the Windows 10 SDK in Visual Studio."
[image]

As I'm using office PC I can not reinstall windows in any way. Can anyone suggest me solution please?

I tried reinstallation as well as tried some forum solutions. Nothing worked for me!

Comment: Adding details message here.

Comment: Here is the error I'm experiencing...
C:\Users\Y26950AL>flutter doctor
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.9, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1556], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.4.2)
    ! Unable to locate a Windows 10 SDK. If building fails, install the Windows 10 SDK in Visual Studio.
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[√] Connected device (2 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and resolved it by installing Visual Studio Build Tools.

The Flutter documentation at https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows#windows-setup advises to install either Visual Studio or Visual Studio Build Tools. Be sure to include the "Desktop development with C++"  component when installing (you'll see it as an option during the installation process).

Answer (score 0):

Try to troubleshoot by running `flutter doctor -vv` in cmd.